# Can we add clickable text or button to terminal/console in python?

Tags: python

For example this is my function:

```
def get_sum(item1, item2):
  print(int(item1) + int(item2))
```

But I want to trigger that function when user clicks at a certain item in command prompt or any terminal.
**Main question:-**
Is it possible to run functions by clicking in terminal?

**Extra**
And I also saw VS-Code extension development output in terminal. when I run `yo code` it shows very nice thing. And user can select the things with the arrow keys and press enter to run it. So could this also be possible in python?
[image]

**Thank you!**

Comment: First we need to discuss if you can make an URL clickable on terminal because it is same in theory . Yes its possible you can anchor an hypertext and FLink but it has a bothering process and not comfortable at all but it is not allowed for functions or built-in scripts so your answer is no you cant do that for functions

Comment: But I don't want to open urls I just want to complete the things within the terminal itself. By the way thanks for comments and please consider upvotinf if you fell the question interesting.  And If yes then how to add clickable item in terminal. Thank you!

Comment: it was not about url's I just tried to explain how terminal works for built scripts it has no tolerance to make them clickable.

Comment: Ok, you meant "Yes we can add clickable text in terminal with python". I understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about key pressing but I found myself an answer:-
We can use the `keyboard` module.

```py
import keyboard 

abc = True

def run_func():
  print('Hi, welcome!')
  print('If you want to do this, press A or press B for doing that.')
  while abc:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
      print('This function is run!')
      abc = True

    elif keyboard.is_pressed('b'):
      print('That function is run!')
      abc = True

print('To start press S')
while abc:
  if keyboard.is_pressed('S'): 
    run_func()
  abc = True
```

Use: When we press key we can run functions and many things!

Comment: You need TUI library which has that capability (if you need it easy way) or just write it from scratch (hard way) but then you must first execute certain ANSI code (you can find them on Xterm's site, but remember that terminal that you are working on or are targeting must support it too)

Comment: Then capture output asynchronously and then compare click position on you terminal's widgets/text's position and if they overlap it is click. TUI libraries I recommend are textual, py_cui, npyscreen, picotui and blessings, although there are more of them.

Answer (score 7):

edit: you can't trigger functions by clicking stuff *in python*, but i think you can in c++

I'm gonna be using the curses module, there is also a ported version for windows, but i'm not sure thats gonna work...

This code is a bit complicated

```
import curses

# define the menu function
def menu(title, classes, color='white'):
  # define the curses wrapper
  def character(stdscr,):
    attributes = {}
    # stuff i copied from the internet that i'll put in the right format later
    icol = {
      1:'red',
      2:'green',
      3:'yellow',
      4:'blue',
      5:'magenta',
      6:'cyan',
      7:'white'
    }
    # put the stuff in the right format
    col = {v: k for k, v in icol.items()}

    # declare the background color

    bc = curses.COLOR_BLACK

    # make the 'normal' format
    curses.init_pair(1, 7, bc)
    attributes['normal'] = curses.color_pair(1)


    # make the 'highlighted' format
    curses.init_pair(2, col[color], bc)
    attributes['highlighted'] = curses.color_pair(2)


    # handle the menu
    c = 0
    option = 0
    while c != 10:

        stdscr.erase() # clear the screen (you can erase this if you want)

        # add the title
        stdscr.addstr(f"{title}\n", curses.color_pair(1))

        # add the options
        for i in range(len(classes)):
            # handle the colors
            if i == option:
                attr = attributes['highlighted']
            else:
                attr = attributes['normal']
            
            # actually add the options

            stdscr.addstr(f'> ', attr)
            stdscr.addstr(f'{classes[i]}' + '\n', attr)
        c = stdscr.getch()

        # handle the arrow keys
        if c == curses.KEY_UP and option > 0:
            option -= 1
        elif c == curses.KEY_DOWN and option < len(classes) - 1:
            option += 1
    return option
  return curses.wrapper(character)
```

that was the menu function, now here's an example of how to use the function

```
print(f"output:", menu('TEST', ['this will return 0','this will return 1', 'this is just to show that you can do more options then just two'], 'blue'))
```

the syntax of the function goes like this

```
menu('title', ['options', 'optionssssssss'], 'color (optional)')
```

here are the available colors:

red
green
yellow
blue
magenta
cyan
white

the output of the example code looks like this:
[image: gif]

you can install the version for windows using this command: `python -m pip install windows-curses`

but i don't think it even works with python 3

also sorry if this post is bad, its my first answer on stackoverflow

Comment: Yessssssssss! This works perfectly fine even in Python-3.9. Thank you @name

Comment: This is more than a full answer with implementation, Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

this can help somebody

```py
from tkinter import colorchooser,Tk,messagebox
from colored import fg,bg,attr
import win32console
import threading
import win32gui
import win32api
import colorama
import atexit
import mouse
import time
import sys
import os

class console:
    def __init__(self):
        self._is_enabled = False
        self._last_pos = (0,0)
        self.hwnd = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
        atexit.register(lambda:self.set_input(True))
    def _mouse_thread(self):
        while True:
            if self.get_mouse_position()[1] > 30:
                if self.is_input():
                    self._set_input(False)
            else:
                if not self.is_input():
                    self._set_input(True)
    def _focus_thread(self):
        while True:
            if win32gui.GetForegroundWindow() != self.hwnd:
                win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self.hwnd)
    def run_focus_thread(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self._focus_thread,daemon=1).start()
    def run_moveable_thread(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self._mouse_thread,daemon=1).start()
    def get_position(self):
        return win32gui.GetWindowRect(self.hwnd)[:2]
    def get_mouse_position(self):
        try:
            pos = win32gui.GetCursorPos()
            self._last_pos = pos
        except:
            pos = self._last_pos
        return (pos[0]-self.get_position()[0]-7,
                pos[1]-self.get_position()[1]-30)
    def _set_input(self,value):
        win32gui.EnableWindow(self.hwnd,value)
    def set_input(self,value):
        self._is_enabled = value
        win32gui.EnableWindow(self.hwnd,value)
    def is_input(self):
        return win32gui.IsWindowEnabled(self.hwnd)
    def set_focus(self):
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self.hwnd)
        win32gui.SetFocus(self.hwnd)
    def is_focus(self):
        return win32gui.GetForegroundWindow() == self.hwnd and \
               self.get_mouse_position()[1] >= 30 and \
               self.get_mouse_position()[0] > 0 and \
               self.get_mouse_position()[0] <= self.get_size()[0]-7 and \
               self.get_mouse_position()[1] <= self.get_size()[1]
    def get_size(self):
        return (win32gui.GetWindowRect(self.hwnd)[2]-7,
                win32gui.GetWindowRect(self.hwnd)[3]-30)
    def set_size(self,w,h):
        win32gui.MoveWindow(self.hwnd,*self.get_position(),int(w),int(h),True)
    def set_position(self,x,y):
        win32gui.MoveWindow(self.hwnd,int(x),int(y),*self.get_size(),True)
    def set_rect(self,x,y,w,h):
        win32gui.MoveWindow(self.hwnd,int(x),int(y),int(w),int(h),True)
    def set_center(self):
        self.set_position(get_screen_size()[0]/2-self.get_size()[0]/2,
                          get_screen_size()[1]/2-self.get_size()[1]/2)
    def set_title(self,title):
        win32gui.SetWindowText(self.hwnd,title)
console = console()

def get_screen_size():
    return (win32api.GetSystemMetrics(0),
            win32api.GetSystemMetrics(1))

font_size = [8.2,15.5]

class canvas:
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.sp = (width*font_size[0],height*font_size[1])
        self.width, self.height = width, height
        self.changed = True
        self.pixels = [[" " for i in range(self.width)] for i in range(self.height)]
        console.set_size(self.sp[0]+30,self.sp[1]+10)
    def clear(self):
        # os.system("cls")
        print("\033[H\033[J",end="")
    def fill(self,symbol=" ",update=True):
        self.pixels = [[symbol for i in range(self.width)] for i in range(self.height)]
        self.changed = True
        if update: self.update()
    def update(self):
        self.changed = False
        out = ""
        for y in self.pixels:
            for x in y:
                out += x
            out += "\n"
        self.clear()
        print(out,end="")
    def set(self,x,y,symbol,update=True):
        if x < self.width and y < self.height:
            self.pixels[y][x] = symbol
            self.changed = True
            if update: self.update()
    def write(self,x,y,text,update=True):
        self.changed = True
        for n,s in enumerate(text):
            self.set(x+n,y,s,False)
        if update: self.update()
    def get(self,x,y):
        return self.pixels[y][x]
    def all(self):
        return self.pixels
    def get_mouse_position(self):
        return (console.get_mouse_position()[0]/self.sp[0]*self.width,
                (console.get_mouse_position()[1]/(self.sp[1]-font_size[1]*4)*self.height))

def color_symbol(color):
    return fg(color)+bg(color)+"#"+attr('reset')


# -------   create canvas   -------

console.set_title("hello world button")  # set console title
console.run_moveable_thread()  # run thread that prohibits clicking on the console
win = canvas(64,34)            # creating canvas


# -------   create buttons   -------

btns = []
def btn(text,x,y,cb):
    btns.append([text,x,y,cb,False])

def btncallback():
    Tk().withdraw()
    messagebox.showinfo("hello world","Hello World!")

btn("click me!",25,15,btncallback)


# -------   create main view   -------

for i in btns:
    win.set(i[1],i[2],i[0][0],False)
    win.write(i[1]+1,i[2],i[0][1:][:-1],False)
    win.set(i[1]+len(i[0])-1,i[2],i[0][-1],False)
win.update()


# -------   main loop   -------


run = True
while run:
    if win.changed:
        win.update()
    if console.is_focus():
        pos = win.get_mouse_position()
        pos = (round(pos[0]),round(pos[1]))
        if mouse.is_pressed("left"):
            for i in btns:
                if pos[0] >= i[1] and pos[0] <= i[1]+len(i[0]) \
                            and pos[1] == i[2]+1 and not i[4]:
                    win.set(i[1],i[2],fg("black")+bg("white")+i[0][0],False)
                    win.write(i[1]+1,i[2],i[0][1:][:-1],False)
                    win.set(i[1]+len(i[0])-1,i[2],i[0][-1]+attr("reset"),False)
                    i[4] = True
        else:
            for i in btns:
                if i[4]:
                    win.set(i[1],i[2],i[0][0],False)
                    win.write(i[1]+1,i[2],i[0][1:][:-1],False)
                    win.set(i[1]+len(i[0])-1,i[2],i[0][-1],False)
                    i[4] = False
                    i[3]()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).